# urlencode() the 'asterisk' (star?) character

Tags: java, php, urlencode

I'm testing **PHP** `urlencode()` vs. **Java** `java.net.URLEncoder.encode()`.

**Java**

```
String all = "";
for (int i = 32; i < 256; ++i) {
    all += (char) i;
}

System.out.println("All characters:         -||" + all + "||-");
try {
    System.out.println("Encoded characters:     -||" + URLEncoder.encode(all, "utf8") + "||-");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**PHP**

```
$all = "";
for($i = 32; $i < 256; ++$i)
{
    $all = $all.chr($i);
}

echo($all.PHP_EOL);
echo(urlencode(utf8_encode($all)).PHP_EOL);
```

All characters seem to be encoded in the same way with both functions, except for the 'asterisk' character that is not encoded by Java, and translated to %2A by PHP. Which behaviour is supposed to be the 'right' one, if any?

Note: I tried with `rawurlencode()`, too - no luck.

Comment: I've asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085992/when-should-an-asterisk-be-encoded-in-an-http-url) to try to get a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is okay to have a `*` in a URL, (but it is also okay to have it in its encoded form).

[RFC1738: Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) states the following:

> **Reserved:**
>
> [...]
>
> Usually a URL has the same interpretation when an octet is
>     represented by a character and when it encoded. However, this is not
>     true for reserved characters: encoding a character reserved for a
>     particular scheme may change the semantics of a URL.
>
> Thus, only alphanumerics, **the special characters `"$-_.+!*'(),"`**, and
>     reserved characters used for their reserved purposes **may be used
>     unencoded** within a URL.
>
> **On the other hand, characters that are not required to be encoded
>     (including alphanumerics) may be encoded** within the scheme-specific
>     part of a URL, as long as they are not being used for a reserved
>     purpose.

Comment: +1 In fact, from the set `$-_.+!*'(),`, Java uses only `-_.*` in unencoded form: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: And the only difference between Java and PHP seems to be the asterisk: PHP uses `%2A` while Java uses `*`.

Answer (score 8):

[Wikipedia suggests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) that `*` is a *reserved character* when it comes to URIs, and that it must be encoded if not used for the reserved purpose. According to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-12), pages 12-13:

> URIs include components and subcomponents that are delimited by
> characters in the "reserved" set.  These characters are called
> "reserved" because they may (or may not) be defined as delimiters by
> the generic syntax, by each scheme-specific syntax, or by the
> implementation-specific syntax of a URI's dereferencing algorithm.
> If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved
> character's purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must be
> percent-encoded before the URI is formed.

```
  reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims

  gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"

  sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

(The fact that [the URL RFC](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) still allows the `*` character to go unencoded is that is *doesn't* have a reserved purpose i URLs, and as such doesn't have to be encoded. So wether you have to encode it or not depends on what sort of URI you're creating.)

Comment: Could you please include the quote from the page that states that `*` should be encoded?

Comment: @aioobe: Done. There seems to be a discrepancy between the URL and URI RFCs, where the URL RFC in effect overrides the URI RFC requirement to encode `*`. So the answer really depends on what kind of URI you're creating.

Comment: `urlencode` and `java.net.URLEncoder` indicates that he's after a URL though.

Comment: RFC3986 explicitly states that it updates RFC1738, so I would think that any inconsistency would be resolved in favor of RFC3986. RFC3986 says that a URL is an example of a URI, and if URIs must have the asterisk encoded, then the URL should as well. But various online tools do it differently (see, e.g., http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ and http://www.url-encode-decode.com/.)

Answer (score 2):

[Javadoc of `URLEncoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) refers to the HTML specification:

> This class contains static methods for converting a String to the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME format. For more information about HTML form encoding, consult the HTML specification.

[HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) is quite unclear regarding this question and refers to [RFC1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), which is quoted by aioobe:

> Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by '+', and then reserved characters are escaped as described in [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by '%HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as "CR LF" pairs (i.e., '%0D%0A').

However, [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#url-encoded-form-data) directly states that `*` should not be encoded:

> - If the character isn't in the range U+0020, **U+002A**, U+002D, U+002E, U+0030 to U+0039, U+0041 to U+005A, U+005F, U+0061 to U+007A
>     Replace the character with a string formed as follows:
>     ...
> - Otherwise
>     Leave the character as is.